# VS 2017 for Mac Error MSB3073

Tags: c#, macos, msbuild, mono, visual-studio-mac

when I build my project I have this error

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Error MSB3073: The command "xcopy "/Users/max/core/ExternalInterfaces/Betinaction.ExtTransactions/Betinaction.ExtTransactions/bin/Debug/*.dll" "/Users/max/core//../packages/BetInAction.Core.1.0.0/" /Y" exited with code 127. (MSB3073) (Betinaction.ExtTransactions)

and this error moves me to this line of code(this line is in Exec tag in code):
WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)"

this is the file where that line is:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Comment: well xcopy is not build-in on macs, change your PostBuild command to use something that works on MacOS

Comment: @splincool, any update for your question? Could you get any useful info from the comment and the answer? If not, please let us to know.

Comment: I think it depends on my project because nothing helps me, I still can't build it.

Answer (score 1):

You should carefully choose what commands to use on non-Windows platforms. One example can be found here,

https://github.com/lextm/obfuscar/blob/master/Console/Obfuscar.Console.csproj#L104

- `rename` -> `mv`
- `del` -> `rm`

In your case, `xcopy` -> `cp`

Information about how to use `cp` can be found here,

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html